# Gulp-autoprefixer throwing ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, autoprefixer

I try to make a gulp compile my sass then autoprefixit with `gulp-autoprefixer` but i'm getting an error.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('test', function(){
    gulp.src('_sass/main.sass')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer()) 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css')); 
});
```

I'm trying to run this `Gulpfile.js` and i'm using :

```
"gulp": "~3.9.0",
"gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.1",
```

and NPM version `1.3.10`

When i run `gulp test` i get this :

```
/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:152
        this.processing = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                              ^
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at LazyResult.async (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:152:31)
    at LazyResult.then (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:75:21)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/index.js:28:13)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:160:12)
    at doWrite (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:326:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:312:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:239:11)
    at write (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/home/matei/Tests/test-4/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
```

I don't really know what i'm doing wrong. Is not working when i use sass or plain css. I think is something with my files.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Sass (or CSS for that matter), when the error is being thrown by Autoprefixer.

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution or not.... but your NPM version is out of date.  Try updating npm and all your packages, I've run into weird quirks like this before while running older builds.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I updated node.js to the latest version using :

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

for my Ubuntu machine, as shown [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall).

After that i updated NPM using :

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

As shown [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node).

Now the `gulp-autoprefixer` start working but i got an error from `gulp-sass`. I updated it using this instruction :

1. Delete your node_modules folder
2. Remove gulp-sass from your package.json file
3. Remove node-sass from your package.json file (if you have it in there)
4. Run npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
5. Update your Gulp task as required

Found [here](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/wiki/Update-to-the-latest-Gulp-Sass).Now i have `"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"` and this fixed all my problems.

Thanks for advice and help.

Comment: You can get `node-sass` working with `npm rebuild node-sass` after upgrading node.

Comment: just worked great. thanks. also the console message asks to run this command when you encounter error while running task

Comment: This is indeed a NodeJS version issue, see https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/45

Comment: Good instructions. OS-agnostic instructions can be found at https://nodesource.com/services/upgrade-self-service

Comment: I didn't need those steps:
`sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable` and used `npm rebuild node-sass` to fix node-sass problem. :)

Answer (score 78):

Had the same issue. For me, updating node didn't work but adding this at the very beginning of my gulpfile did:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

Comment: This is a good "hotfix", the better solution is to upate node.js (see the answer of @Matei)

Comment: @MonkeyKing like I said in my answer, updating node didn't solve the problem

Comment: what package? I get `cannot find module es6-promise`

Comment: @Victor try running `npm install es6-promise` in your terminal

Answer (score 29):

Install es6-promise in ur project location where package.json exists

```
npm install es6-promise
```

Then make the first line of your gulpfile.js be the following code:

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the question directly but it might be useful for people that get this error when trying to  run the ionic 2 tutorial.

As pointed by other answers the problem is that `es6-promise` is missing.

I got the same error when trying to start the ionic 2 tutorial (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial):
(my ionic 2 version is 2.0.0-beta.25 and latest tutorial commit is ed9ef2fcce887e4d1c08c375c849b06b8394bad7)

This is the stack trace I got when trying to run the app with `ionic serve`:

```
Running 'serve:before' gulp task before serve
[18:37:00] Starting 'clean'...
[18:37:01] Finished 'clean' after 1.02 s
[18:37:01] Starting 'watch'...
[18:37:01] Starting 'sass'...
[18:37:01] Starting 'html'...
[18:37:01] Starting 'fonts'...
[18:37:01] Starting 'scripts'...
[18:37:01] Finished 'scripts' after 62 ms
[18:37:01] Finished 'html' after 72 ms
[18:37:01] Finished 'fonts' after 77 ms
Caught exception:
 ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
    at LazyResult.async (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:157:31)
    at LazyResult.then (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:79:21)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/index.js:24:6)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:159:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:147:83)
    at doWrite (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:313:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:302:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at DestroyableTransform.ondata (/home/stitakis/dev/playground/ionic2/myTutorial/node_modules/ionic-gulp-sass-build/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:531:20)
    at DestroyableTransform.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Again, as pointed by other answers, this is how to solve this:

1. edit gulpfile.js and add in line 6: `require('es6-promise').polyfill();`
2. install the missing dependency with: `npm install es6-promise --save`

After this changes, the problem was fixed and I was able to start the local server.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, all I needed to do was use the npm install es6-promise with the --save, and use this require with .pollyfill, using .Promise() as in an awnser above did not work for me.